# How to enhance speed to compare a list of ID to a known list of ID from MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

In my code, I use a process that takes a lot of time, this is web-scraping, I need to know which ID is already known:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
mydb = client['db']
mycol = mydb['collection']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    [...]
    for item in driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a'):
        flag = True
        url = item.get_attribute('href')
        myid = re.sub(r'.*item/([0-9a-f-]+)\?.*', r'\1', url)
        # I iterate over all known MongoDB ID's to find a match or not
        # It takes too much time to compare
        for oupid in mycol.find({ }, { "Id": 1, "_id": 0}):
            if myid == oupid['Id']:
                flag = False

        if not flag:
            continue
```

Any recommendation?
It takes 6mn to parse the site, and most of the time is waste to compare IDs.

Comment: I wouldn't do double loops like you have here. Why not first extract all ids from the db and then for every page create a list of ids there and do a set intersection with database ids?

Comment: I don't understand the outer loop (can you just create an array of the relevant `myid`'s?) and looping over the entire contents of the MongoDB collection is very wasteful.  The inner loop could be replaced with something like `mycol.find_one({ "Id": myid}, { "Id": 1, "_id": 0})`.  If it if finds it, `{"Id": myid}` will be returned, if not `None` will be returned.  If you have an index on `"Id"` this will be a _covered_ query and the collection won't even need to be scanned. _"I need to know which ID to discard"_ What does that mean?  Your code doesn't show any _"discarding"_.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I post my answer. Can you confirm it's the good way please?

Comment: Fixed description, removed 'discard' for 'I need to know which ID is already known'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved like this, 2 times faster than previous:

```
# FIXME compare time JS vs Selenium
items_urls = driver.execute_script("""
xpath = '//a';
x = [];
result = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
for (let i = 0; i < result.snapshotLength; i++) {
    const element = result.snapshotItem(i);
    x.push(element.href);
};
return x;
""")

items_ids = [re.sub(r'.*item/([0-9a-f-]+)\?.*', r'\1', url) for url in items_urls]

oupids = collection.find({ }, { "Id": 1, "_id": 0})
oupids = [item['Id'] for item in oupids]

# Remove intersection ID's
items_list = list(set(items_ids).difference(set(oupids)))

for myid in items_list:
    item = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//a[contains(@href, "/item/{myid}")]')
    url = item.get_attribute('href')
```